# Div not visible in html and css

Tags: css, html, invisible

I am facing a little problem with a  in html and css.I want to create a menu in a top left corner of the page, but my div won't dipslay.Would be grateful for any solutions.
HTML

```
<div class = "topMenu">
<div id = "search"></div>
<div id = "register"></div>
```

CSS

```
body {
background:url('image.jpg') no-repeat;
-moz-background-size:cover; 
-webkit-background-size:cover;
-o-background-size:cover;
background-size:cover;
background-color:black;
}

#topMenu{
position:absolute;
width:70px;
float:right;
background-color:red;
}
```

Comment: where is the closing </div>?

Comment: `float: right;` is not required when you are using `absolute` also, always wrap a position absolute div inside a relative positioned container, or else it will run out in the wild and you'll spend days to figure out

Comment: It seems that you code is incorrect. Why do you have the closing Div tag at the end of the CSS section? You also miss a closing Div tag in the HTML section

Comment: # is used for adding style considering id. But here topMenu is class. So change #topMenu to .topMenu. Or change class="topMenu" to id="topMenu".

Answer (score 2):

See this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/TRp3A/

There `#topMenu` is changed to `.topMenu` in css, otherwise class will not be applied to corresponding div. And I've added there height just to make div visible as there is no content and it is 0 height by default.

```
.topMenu{
    position:absolute;
    width:70px;
    float:right;
    background-color:red;
    height:40px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because your div#topMenu has no height.

Besides,you'd better add a closing ,which may cause some problem in the future.

Comment: Already figured it out.I had a mistake, because in the css the sould've been clas,not id.But thanx everyone

Comment: @user2167174 If you've figured out, then please add an answer to this question. Don't let this question get wasted. This is meant to be helpful for future visitors as well. Since an answer is already added (referring to the one by @FAngel), choose that as the correct answer.